# Working with backend configuration objects with VueJS

Tags: php, ajax, vue.js, architecture

Coming from the world of pure PHP for both backend and frontend, I'm now using a VueJS app consuming a PHP API.

Let's say I'd like to render a page with a form. In this form I have a select field "Gender" with options "Male" and "Female".

In PHP, I would have a config file with something like this :

```
$config['GENDER'] = [
    "M" => [
       "label" => "Male",
    ],
    "F" => [
       "label" => "Female",
    ],
];
```

Which I will use to create the select options in the frontend, but also use in my backend for some field validation for example.

In PHP this is fine because the backend and frontend only needs to require this file.

Working with VueJS, how do you solve this issue ? 
Do you make an AJAX call to the backend to retrieve those data on app load ? Do you duplicate shared configuration in both frontend and backend ?

Answer (score 0):

Well either of your suggestions will work.

You can simply provide the data in your php/html script like so:

(quotes might need to be escaped):

```php
<my-vue-component :genders="<?php echo json_encode(...); ?>"></my-vue-component>
```

```html
<script>
    // MyVueComponent.vue
    export default {
        props: {
            genders: Array
        }
    }
</script>
```

Or request the data in the `mounted()` hook in your Vue component like so:

```html
<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            this.$http.get('/api/genders').then((response) {
                this.genders = response.data;
            });
        },
        data() {
            return {
                genders: []
            }
        }
    ...
    }
</script>
```

This last one is more difficult to implement since you need to create a JSON endpoint (an API). However the advantage of this is that you can reload this data more easily.

So if your data is expected to change fast (***dynamic data***) then this is the way to go. If it is ***static data*** then you should provide it through the component properties. The data will then only be renewed on page reload.